# Why does my ajax call takes so long?

Tags: c#, .net, json, ajax

when I make an AJAX call to receive the JSON-object defined in this c# code I have to  46+ seconds to receive this object. The object itself is only 12kb large. Is it because of my c# code(which doesn't take that long to execute?) of is it something else. Im testing it on my localhost IIS server.

This is my code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult LoadAudit(int id, string sheet)
    {
        FactsCustomerRepository<Cateringaudit> repo = new FactsCustomerRepository<Cateringaudit>();
        //IQueryable<Cateringaudit> result = repo.GetAll(i => i.State == 1);
        Cateringaudit result1 = repo.Get(id);
        WorkBook wb = new WorkBook();
        wb.read(new MemoryStream(result1.ExcelData));
        object[] jsonObjects = new object[3];
        //sheetnames to collect data from
        string[] sheetNames = { "contract", "proces", "output" };
        //itterate trough all sheets in excel file
        for (int sheetCount = 0; sheetCount < sheetNames.Length; sheetCount++)
        {
            wb.Sheet = wb.findSheetByName(sheetNames[sheetCount]);
            //Create new array with same lenght as rows with data
            Dictionary<string, string[]> excelData = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
            //iterate trough all rows in worksheet
            for (int i = 1; i < wb.LastRow + 2; i++)
            {
                excelData.Add(blabla);
                jsonObjects[sheetCount] = excelData;
            }
        }
        return Json(jsonObjects);
    }
```

Comment: is all of the above code  required for the question?

Comment: Try to log each step of the important line. The log should have timestamp. Then, you can investigate from there.

Comment: where does the question refer to the code above? this has absolutly nothing to do with AJAX. please modify your question

Comment: Use the code profiler (e.g. one included in VS) to find a bottleneck in your code - getting data from the repo, working with an excel, and etc.

Comment: You can debug that code and check what takes so long. You can use the StopWatch class to get the exact amount of time required by that code. In my opinion the issue is not related to the ajax call, it's related to the logic you implemented on the server side that needs to complete before passing the data to theclient.

Answer (score 0):

Going on a limb here: opening Excelsheets in C# is ridiculously slow. There are great libraries out there which are way faster:

EEPLUS: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

But to rule out Excel first: have you tried returning a static JsonObject and not use excel?

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult LoadAudit(int id, string sheet)
{
    return Json(); // something like this
}
```

Comment: It is indeed the Excel what makes it so slow, I returned a static JSON object. At first I was using Spreadsheetlight, now I am using SmartXLS which I read about was much faster than spreadsheetlight.